# How does String.ToLowerInvariant() determine to what string/character it must convert?

Tags: c#, unicode

As we know Unicode was invented to solve codepage problem and to represent all characters of all (well not all but most) languages of the world. Next we have unicode transformation formats - how to represent unicode character in computer bytes:

- utf-8 one character can take from 1 to 4 bytes
- utf-16 one character takes 2 bytes, or 2*2bytes = 4bytes (.NET uses this)
- utf-32 one character always takes 4 bytes (I heard Python uses this)

So far, ok. Next we take for example two languages:

English in united kingdom (en-GB) and slovenian in Slovenia (sl-SI). English has next characters: a, b, c, d, e, ... x, y, z. Slovene has the same characters except x,y and it has additional characters: č, š, ž. If I run below code:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sl-SI");
string upperCase = "č".ToUpper(); // returns Č, which is correct based on sl-SI culture

// returns Č, how does it know that it must convert č to Č. 
// What if some other language has character č, and č in that language converts to X.
// How does it determine to what character it must convert?
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("tr-TR");
string upperCase1 = "č".ToUpperInvariant();
```

We can take [turkish example](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html): 
Lowercase “i” becomes “İ” (U+0130 “Latin Capital Letter I With Dot Above”) when it moves to uppercase. Similarly, our uppercase “I” becomes “ı” (U+0131 “Latin Small Letter Dotless I”) when it moves to lowercase.

[image: to upper]

[image: to lower]

What if ToUpperInvariant() determines to convert "i" to turkish "İ" and not "I". Is then invariant culture english. Out of scope of this question but, do all languages of the world have upper case for each lower case character? I assume yes, but if they don't, is there a language that has only upper case characters. Yes I know I should go from \u+0000 to \u+FFFF to test this.

Comment: The invariant culture is a fake culture based on English. And many languages don't have a concept of upper and lower case - for example, any of the Chinese languages.

Comment: I think your test with MS SQL Server should be left out - I guess it is affected by the database encoding, which means it should belong on a different question,

Comment: @MatthewWatson aha so it is English. I didn't know about Chinese not having a concept of upper/lower case, thnx.

Comment: Not every lower case character has an upper case counterpart. The letter `ß` in german exists only in it's lower case form.

Comment: @nhahtdh deleted MS SQL Server test, as you pointed out it does belong to the context/question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Unicode standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode8.0.0/ch04.pdf), the sources for Case Mapping Information are

> **UnicodeData.txt:** Contains the case mappings that map to a single character. These do not increase the length of strings, nor do they contain context-dependent mappings.
>
> **SpecialCasing.txt:** Contains additional case mappings that map to more than one character, such as “ß” to “SS”. Also contains context-dependent mappings, with flags to distinguish them from the normal mappings, as well as some locale-dependent mappings.

In [UnicodeData.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt), you'll find:

```
0069;LATIN SMALL LETTER I;Ll;0;L;;;;;N;;;0049;;0049
010C;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CARON;Lu;0;L;0043 030C;;;;N;LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C HACEK;;;010D;
010D;LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON;Ll;0;L;0063 030C;;;;N;LATIN SMALL LETTER C HACEK;;010C;;010C
```

(The last three columns contain the simple uppercase, lowercase and titlecase mapping.)

So, unless there are locale-dependent exceptions, *every* Unicode implementation will use these mappings, resulting in:

```
uppercase(i) = I
uppercase(č) = Č
lowercase(Č) = č
```

The file [SpecialCasing.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/SpecialCasing.txt) says:

> The entries in this file are in the following machine-readable format:
>
> `<code>; <lower>; <title>; <upper>; (<condition_list>;)? # <comment>`

and

> A condition list *overrides the normal behavior* if all of the listed conditions are true.

For Turkish, it contains the following exception:

```
# When uppercasing, i turns into a dotted capital I

0069; 0069; 0130; 0130; tr; # LATIN SMALL LETTER I
```

So, for the Turkish (and Azeri) language:

```
uppercase(i) = İ
```

There are also some exceptions for Lithuanian. Except for these few exceptions, case mappings should always be the same, regardless of the .NET "culture".

Answer (score 2):

The invariant culture is a fake culture based on English, so all "Invariant" conversions will be based on the English ones.

> Do all languages of the world have upper case for each lower case character?

No, they don't. For example, Chinese languages do not have the concept of upper and lower case.

And German has the letter `ß`, which does not have an uppercase version.

Consider:

```
var germanCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture   = germanCulture;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = germanCulture;

string s = "ß";

Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpper()); // Prints ß
Console.WriteLine(s.ToLower()); // Prints ß

// Aside: There's a special "uppercase" ß, but this isn't
// returned from "ß".ToUpper();

string t = "ẞ"; // Special "uppercase" ß.

Console.WriteLine(t == s); // Prints false.

Console.WriteLine(s.ToUpper() == t); // Prints false.
```

(See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E) for details about the strange uppercase `ß` (`ẞ`) which isn't returned from `"ß".ToUpper()`.)

Comment: A related quirk: `ẞ` is as an uppercase `ß`, but its use is inconsistent and so the mapping is one-way (`"ẞ".ToLower().ToUpper() == "ß"`).

Comment: @一二三 `ß` is always lowercase. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case): *"The German letter "ß" orthographically only exists in lower case, as it never occurs at the beginning of a word"* However, there is a special uppercase version, `ẞ`, which looks pretty identical...

Comment: @一二三 Ah yes, I already saw that, but I misread your original post (mistaking `ẞ` for `ß`). :) I've already added some information about that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolowerinvariant(v=vs.110).aspx) remarks:

> The invariant culture represents a culture that is
>   culture-insensitive. **It is associated with the English language** but
>   not with a specific country or region.

Not all the languages have upper case and lower case characters like Chinese, Japanese, Hindi, Marathi etc

Also [this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolowerinvariant-toupperinvariant)

> ToLower is very similar in most places to ToLowerInvariant. The
>   documents indicate that these methods will only change behavior with
>   Turkish cultures. Also, on Windows systems, the file system is
>   case-insensitive, which further limits its use

Answer (score 0):

I am adding some of the important points:-

1. The invariant culture is culture-insensitive; it is associated with the English language but not with any country/region.
2. By using invariant culture will can fix string representation issue and it is not going to be change due to country or region changes.

> Example: We are displaying some date **dd/MM/YYYY** in IST, but in EST it might through some exception or get different meaning, So to come out from like issues, we can use invariant concept.